# I want to toggle menu in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I want to toggle the the side navigation bar for that I am -

> 1. Taken a boolen value toggle_menu to true
> 2. and I am calling a function togg() on button click in the menu bar 
>      which sets the boolean value false anf hence div is toggled

***But problem is*** 
there are  4 button, each button has it's own div container each button is calling function on click `togg()`

which result all the div is opening at the same time.

***But I want to open each div for each button click***

**ts code :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
  export class AppComponent{
   toggle_menu: boolean = true;
    constructor() { }
    togg() {
      return this.toggle_menu = !this.toggle_menu;
      }
  }
```

**html code :**

```
<button class="dropdown-btn" (click)="togg();"> Besics</button>
        <div *ngIf="!toggle_menu">
        <a routerLink="/imp-style"> Implimenting Style  </a>
        </div>

<button class="dropdown-btn" (click)="togg();">Image</button>
        <div *ngIf="!toggle_menu">

        <a routerLink="/slider"> Image Slider</a>
        </div>
<button class="dropdown-btn" (click)="togg();">Forms</button>
        <div *ngIf="!toggle_menu">
        <a routerLink="/signup"> Signup </a>
        <a routerLink="/signup"> Login </a>
        <a routerLink="/signup"> Register </a>
        </div>
<button class="dropdown-btn" (click)="togg();">Service</button>
        <div *ngIf="!toggle_menu">
        <a routerLink="/dipika-task"> Data Display </a>
        <a routerLink="/social-media"> Social Media </a>
        <a routerLink="/student"> Student </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Use more variables? Or an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
export class AppComponent{
   dropdowns = {
    "besics": false,
    "images": false,
    "forms": false, 
    "service": false,
   }

    constructor() { }
    togg(string name) {
      dropwdowns[name] = !dropwdowns[name];
  }
```

And in your html use `*ngIf`

```html
<button class="dropdown-btn" (click)="togg('besics');"> Besics</button>
        <div *ngIf="dropdowns['besics']">
        <a routerLink="/imp-style"> Implimenting Style  </a>
        </div>

<button class="dropdown-btn" (click)="togg('image');">Image</button>
        <div *ngIf="dropdowns['image']">
        <a routerLink="/slider"> Image Slider</a>
        </div>
<button class="dropdown-btn" (click)="togg('forms');">Forms</button>
        <div *ngIf="dropdowns['forms']">
        <a routerLink="/signup"> Signup </a>
             ....
        </div>
<button class="dropdown-btn" (click)="togg('service');">Service</button>
        <div *ngIf="dropdowns['service']">
        <a routerLink="/dipika-task"> Data Display </a>
             ....
</div>
```

Comment: @AnuragRanjan beware of not being DRY though, this seem a bit repetitive

Comment: On putting function 
togg(string name) {
     alert(name);
    this.dropdowns[name] = !this.dropdowns[name];
    }

name which is alert is undefined 
also I am getting error on passing name into the function togg() 
which says ---->> [ts] ',' expected.
(parameter) name: any

Comment: Change it to this:  (click)="togg($event, 'besics')"

And method to this:
    togg($event, name) {
      dropwdowns[name] = !dropwdowns[name];
  }

Answer (score 1):

How about you simplify it even more and get rid of redundancy:

```
export interface MenuItem {
  title: string;
  links: { title: string, link: string }[]
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent{

   menuItems: MenuItem [] = [
     { 
       title: 'Basics' ,
       links: {
         title: 'Implementing Style',
         link: '/imp-style'
       }
     },
     // ... put the rest here
   ];

   activeMenu?: MenuItem;

   toggle(menu: MenuItem): void {
     this.activeMenu = this.activeMenu === menu ? void 0 : menu;
   }

   isActive(menu: MenuItem): boolean {
     return this.activeMenu === menu;
   }
}
```

**template**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let menu of menuItems">
  <button class="dropdown-btn" (click)="toggle(menu)">{{menu.title}}</button>
  <div *ngIf="isActive(menu)">
    <a *ngFor="let link of menu.links" [routerLink]="link.link">{{link.title}}</a>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

and if you want the possibility of more menus open at the same time:

```
activeMenus: MenuItem[] = [];

toggle(menu: MenuItem): void {
  if (this.isActive(menu)) {
    this.activeMenus.splice(this.activeMenus.indexOf(menu), 1);
  } else {
    this.activeMenu.push(menu);
  }
}

isActive(menu: MenuItem): boolean {
  return this.activeMenus.includes(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, all your 4 buttons have a div inside which is depending on the same boolean from your .ts code.

If you want them to toggle independently of each other and that every button toggles its own slider, you will need to have 4 different booleans in your .ts code.

Here is an example:

```
<button class="dropdown-btn" (click)="togg();"> Besics</button>
    <div *ngIf="!toggle_menu1">
    <a routerLink="/imp-style"> Implimenting Style  </a>
    </div>
<button class="dropdown-btn" (click)="togg();">Image</button>
    <div *ngIf="!toggle_menu2">
    <a routerLink="/slider"> Image Slider</a>
    </div>
<button class="dropdown-btn" (click)="togg();">Forms</button>
    <div *ngIf="!toggle_menu3">
    <a routerLink="/signup"> Signup </a>
    <a routerLink="/signup"> Login </a>
    <a routerLink="/signup"> Register </a>
    </div>
<button class="dropdown-btn" (click)="togg();">Service</button>
    <div *ngIf="!toggle_menu4">
    <a routerLink="/dipika-task"> Data Display </a>
    <a routerLink="/social-media"> Social Media </a>
    <a routerLink="/student"> Student </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: after doing that should I change the logic in the function which i am calling which I am calling on button click 


 togg() {
     this.toggle_menu = !this.toggle_menu;
}

Comment: Of course, you'd have to use different toggle methods for each of the booleans. But some of the solutions from others are less redundant than this primitive one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain different flags for each button to make this work..

```
<button class="dropdown-btn" (click)="Besicstogg();"> Besics</button>
        <div *ngIf="!Besicstoggle_menu">
        <a routerLink="/imp-style"> Implimenting Style  </a>
        </div>

<button class="dropdown-btn" (click)="Imagetogg();">Image</button>
        <div *ngIf="!Imagetoggle_menu">

        <a routerLink="/slider"> Image Slider</a>
        </div>
<button class="dropdown-btn" (click)="Formstogg();">Forms</button>
        <div *ngIf="!Formstoggle_menu">
        <a routerLink="/signup"> Signup </a>
        <a routerLink="/signup"> Login </a>
        <a routerLink="/signup"> Register </a>
        </div>
<button class="dropdown-btn" (click)="Servicetogg();">Service</button>
        <div *ngIf="!Servicetoggle_menu">
        <a routerLink="/dipika-task"> Data Display </a>
        <a routerLink="/social-media"> Social Media </a>
        <a routerLink="/student"> Student </a>
         </div>
```

and in ts file

```
 Servicetogg() {
      return this.Servicetoggle_menu = !this.Servicetoggle_menu;
  }
Besicstogg() {
      return this.Besicstoggle_menu = !this.Besicstoggle_menu;
  }
Imagetogg() {
      return this.Imagetoggle_menu = !this.Imagetoggle_menu;
  }
Formstogg() {
      return this.Formstoggle_menu = !this.Formstoggle_menu;
  }
Servicetogg() {
      return this.Servicetoggle_menu = !this.Servicetoggle_menu;
  }
```

Comment: I think, to pass different argument in click function and add condition accordingly in controller is easy than create 4 function even both are not a good practice.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by simply pass the name of menu in `(click)` function and store in a variable.

```html
<li class="list-group-item" (click)="toggleMenu('menu')"> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" >Menu</a>
</li>
```

and in controller use following code:

```ts
toggleMenu(menu: string): void{
    if(this.toggle == true && this.subsetting!='' && this.subsetting!=menu)
    this.toggle = false;

    this.subsetting  = menu;
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
}
```

but first declare the variable in class

```ts
toggle:boolean = false;
subsetting:string ='';
```